# Click in a text view main screen then shown this "java.lang.NullPointerException." this error in logcat.and cant go to forgotpassword.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

When I click the TextView (forgot your password?) in the main screen(main.xml), it cannot direct to forgotpassword.xml and crashes. The other activities are no problem.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Plot Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="Bring Me Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:width="100sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:width="100sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_to_forgotpassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Forgot Your Password?"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.plotout.loginandregister;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // setting default screen to main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button registerScreen = (Button)  findViewById (R.id.btnRegister);

        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        Button loginScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        // Listening to register new account link
        loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        TextView forgotpasswordScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_forgotpassword);

     // Listening to forgot password link
        forgotpasswordScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    };
};
```

forgotpassword.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/images">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Reset your Password"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Enter your Email Id"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="17dp"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/forpas"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/respass"
            android:layout_below="@+id/forpas"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:id="@+id/alert"
            android:layout_below="@+id/respass"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Back to Login"
            android:id="@+id/bktolog"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnback_to_login"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

forgotpasswordActivity.java

```
package com.plotout.loginandregister;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Set View to forgotpassword.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.forgotpassword);

        Button mainScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnback_to_login);

        // Listening to main Screen link
        mainScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws the NPE?

Comment: If you're description is accurate, then the error is probably in `ForgotPasswordActivity`. Please post that class and your logcat.

Comment: sir,i already pos the ForgotPasswordActivity.java and forgotpasword.xml as well..

Comment: You don't have a Button with the ID `btnback_to_login` in the layout xml, so `mainScreen` is null in your code.

Comment: btnback_to_login is there in forgotpassword.xml

Comment: @GopikrishnanV I don't see it at all. I see `android:layout_below="@+id/btnback_to_login"` but never any `android:id="@+id/btnback_to_login"`

Comment: oo..okok..i try it 1st ya

Comment: gopikrishinan v is work..thanks ya..

Comment: can pls tell me what is the problem here??so next time i can avoid this

Comment: thanks Mike.is work ady...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `link_to_forgot_password` to be clickable. See the documentation, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)).

This can also be done in the xml with `android:clickable="true"`